# Gitlab push does not work, pull works perfectly

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a server where I have installed gitlab and have created a project. I modified the post-receive hook where I declared the working tree and the git repo. After that I cloned my project to my local machine and everything went perfectly. When I tried to push I got the following error.

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" master:master

Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 1.35 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
To ssh://server/path/repo.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@server/path/repo.git'


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (6240 ms @ 11/23/2016 2:35:10 PM)
```

It says that the project could not be found but I was able to pull it. Gitlab and the repo are on the same server.

If anyone has any fix, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the result of `git remote -v`? The URL you're pushing to looks odd.

Comment: And what Gitlab version are you using? It looks really ancient

Comment: @das_j GitLab Community Edition 8.13.6

Comment: @Collin is the same url from that command

Comment: Was hoping to see ground truth on both your push and pull URLs. GitLab doesn't typically refer to repositories by a full path like that

Comment: @Collin if I use the gitlab path `git@server:group/repo.git` it returns a `fatal: 'group/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository` when i try to clone it

Comment: If the Gitlab paths aren't working, then something about Gitlab is mis-configured.

Comment: @Collin however every git command works with current path, besides push

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a bad remote address. You can check your remote address using

```
git remote show origin
```

It must appear something like:

```
Push  URL: git@<address>:<project>/<repository_name>.git
```

If you have a bad address, starting with ssh:// or something like that, try changing remote address:

```
git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
```

Proper address will appear in Gitlab project page. You can find more info using `git help remote`

Comment: I tried that and I received fatal: Unable to look up git://gitlab_project_path (port 9418) (A non-recoverable error occurred during a database look-up.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with gitlab database configuration, check it

Answer (score 1):

Change Permission for your repository

Go to setting->Permissions

Click on Expand

Then change **Project visibility** to

**Internal** or **Public**

Answer (score 1):

For this I had to create a personal access token 
  https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens

Once you have a token, you can enter it instead of your password when performing Git operations over HTTPS.

For example:
[image]